# Why boxes have 2 versions on ubuntu software?

Tags: gnome-boxes

In ubuntu software it can be found and installed gnome boxes like two different apps.one version is 42.3-1718426 the other is 44.2-stable.if i try to run the two at same time it doesnt work, only one at time. what is the one that is better? and why there is two versions of the same software? and why i can not run the two apps at same time?

you can find it by typing gnome boxes, one of them and boxes the other one

Comment: There are different deb versions for each release of Ubuntu, plus different versions in each snap channel. Which is which is clearly listed in the "source" section of Ubuntu Software.